# How to say current price in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I have worked out the daily bars range, say from high-low.

I want to be able to say 'From todays open, if the price goes up 50% of yesterdays range then go long.

Saw some people say 'close' is the word for current price, but I don't want to wait for the daily candle to close, I want to enter that long as price hits that 50% during the day.

Just cant figure out how to put that into my code, any ideas or help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 6):

`close` refers to current price in real-time. With every new price change, its value will be updated to the latest price value.

Just plot `close` and watch it in real-time and you will see.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but still not working sadly. 

I'm trying to get this code to work -

Range           = high - close

percentofRange  = (i_percentRange / 100) * Range[1]


// Buy Conditions


var float buyPrice = 0

buyCondition    = close > percentofRange[1] and strategy.position_size == 0 and f_dateFilter

Comment: Also, I am backtesting, not real time / forward testing

Comment: If it's not real time, you won't be having the tick information. Tradingview only has Open, Close, High, Low price values on the historical bars.

Comment: Ok all good. If im on the daily chart then, and I have 'use bar magnifier' on, will it enter my trade intra day still, and how far down will bar magnifier go if im on the daily chart? Thanks